# Visual studio не даёт привязать переменную к элементу управления

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, combobox, mfc

Создаю ComboBox, пытаюсь привязать к нему переменную через  мастер добавления переменной-члена. То есть тыкаю ПКМ по комбобоксу, нажимаю "добавить переменную". Но вот что выдаёт VisualStudio.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должен предлагать другое. Вот что написано на docs.microsoft по этому поводу:

- При добавлении переменной-члена, не являющейся элементом управления диалогового окна, выберите один из доступных типов в списке:

> char short double unsigned charf loat unsigned int int     unsigned long
>   long

- При добавлении переменной-члена для элемента управления диалогового окна это поле заполняется типом объекта, возвращаемого для элемента управления или значения. Если выбрать Элемент управления, то поле Тип переменной будет указывать базовый класс элемента управления, выбранного в поле Идентификатор элемента управления. Если элемент управления диалогового окна может содержать значение и вы выбрали Значение, то Тип переменной будет указывать соответствующий тип для значения, которое может содержать элемент управления. 
  Это значение зависит от выбора в поле Идентификатор элемента управления и не может быть изменено.

То есть на самом Docs.Microsoft написано, что то, что вылетает у меня - оно вылетает только тогда, когда пытаешься добавить переменную НЕ к элементу управления. А я пытаюсь добавить к элементу управления, и у меня должен выпадать второй вариант, с возможностью выбрать тип переменной как базовый класс того элемента управления, к которому я пытаюсь прикрепить переменную(в моём случае - это создать переменную типа CComboBox, а он мне даёт создать только фундаментальные типы)

И я не могу понять в чём проблема.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Нашёл ответ. Проблема заключалась в версии Visual Studio. Стоило обновиться до последней - проблема исправилась[image: введите сюда описание изображения]